# Refactoring question: Extract as widget/method/variable... What are pros and cons?

Tags: flutter, dart, refactoring

All three of them do basically the same thing. What are the best practices? In which case shall I use which extracting way? What is the standard?

I guess these could be some points that could matter:

- readability
- performance
- number of lines

#### Example:

Extract the Container. Which way would you prefer and why?

```dart
class Example extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

### 1. Extract Container as Widget (+6 lines):

```dart
class Example extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ExtractedAsWidget();
  }
}

class ExtractedAsWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

### 2. Extract Container as Method (+1 (in some cases 3) line):

```dart
class Example extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return buildContainer();
  }

  Container buildContainer() => Container();
}
```

### 3. Extract Container as Variable (+1 line):

```dart
class Example extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var container = Container();
        return container;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Extracting as `Widget` is the best practice as the Flutter framework can optimize widgets rather than methods or variables. But for this particular case, I would extract `Container` as `method`. Extracting as `Widget` would be too overkill.

**Extracting as Variable**

Extracting as `variable` should only be done when your widget is fixed, being used only in a single file & doesn't need any parameters.

**Extracting as Method**

Extracting as `method` should be done when your widget is being used only in a single file (and it can also use some parameters for additional customization). It also increases code readability.

**Extracting as Widget**

Extracting as `Widget` is the most optimal way to create a widget that is being used multiple times in different files. Flutter recommends creating as much `StatelessWidget` as possible.

The most simple example that I can suggest is the use of buttons. Every app has a fixed primary color button that we use. So, instead of creating a variable or method, we should create a `StatelessWidget` of that button & use that in multiple screens of our app.